# What branch of topology deals with expanding foam-like surfaces or structures in 3d+?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

I want to describe motion along geodesics in a foam-like structure where the bubbles wouldn't be spherical as their locally discontinuous expansion—every part of the foam expands at different rates—follows a quadratic rather than linear function, and the bubbles' surfaces aren't planes but 3d space, so the entire thing requires 4 spatial dimensions.

If you dimension-reduce or flatlander-ize it then you might visualize it as a rubber surface that gets stretched continuously with local extrema that expand faster than the main surface so you end up with blisters, bubbles or protuberances everywhere.

Note that expansion as well as motion are physical concepts involving a temporal rather than spatial dimension. Not exactly sure what pure mathematicians do—from what I've seen you don't really talk about 'time'?

Anyway the question is what this might remind people of or which branch of geometry/topology would deal with such ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> _Riemannian geometry_ is likely to have some bearing, if I understand qualitatively what you're asking, but there are going to be some technical snags. Offhand: 1. There is a notion of "time" for particles moving along geodesics, and a notion of "time" for the change of shape. Whether or not these are the same, we'll need a definition of geodesics for a time-varying metric. 2. When a geodesic hits a surface boundary there is a reasonably well-defined way to continue, but when a geodesic hits an edge or vertex matters are more complicated.

Comment: Thanks! It appears you saw I'm playing with a toy universe—zero notion of electromagnetism, material diversity (different kinds of hadrons) nor even energy—purely for fun. Neither Newtonian-Cartesian nor (recognizably for me anyway) Einstein-curved-space derived in that it it's not static nor expanding uniformly. For a long time I thought closed geodesics aka orbits don't work but now it seems I can imagine how, at least in 3d flatland. So 1. is pertinent: geodesics aren't fixed; about 2. there aren't any boundaries, vertices or edges—everything is one huge continuous surface or boiling foam.

Comment: Just a note because I'm chuffed about the cool result: While this is purely to model gravity differently (one point where it meets measurement better than received wisdom is with gravity at the bottom of a mine shaft) I didn't intend it to say anything about the nature of matter but it naturally emerges as just space at a higher concentration along the 4th dimension: Wherever there is a lot of gravity, space is more sharply deformed/deforming (it never stops) so from our 3d vantage point there is just more space or foam surface in one spot. So space = matter here.

Comment: About 1. there is no notion of particles as point charges, it's expanding bubbles all the the way down.